# Warning: mysqli::query(): (21000/1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm running queries and receiving the following PHP error message: `Warning: mysqli::query(): (21000/1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row`

When I drop these queries into phpMyAdmin, I get this message: `#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`

PHP Version 5.5.18,
MySql Version 5.6.21

Bad Query

```
select *, 
  (select stime 
    from racetype_standards 
    where eventID = 8 and stypeID=st.id and gender = 2 and division = 1) 
    as standscore, 
  (select floor(stime / 60) 
    from racetype_standards 
    where eventID = 8 and stypeID=st.id and gender = 2 and division = 1) 
    as standminutes, 
  (select (stime % 60) 
    from racetype_standards 
    where eventID = 8 and stypeID=st.id and gender = 2 and division = 1) 
    as standseconds, 
  (select substring_index(stime, '.', -1)
    from racetype_standards 
    where eventID = 8 and stypeID=st.id and gender = 2 and division = 1) 
    as standhunds, 
  (select ecomment 
    from racetype_standards 
    where eventID = 8 and stypeID=st.id and gender = 2 and division = 1) 
    as ecomm 
  from standards_type st 
  where active = 1 
  order by displayOrder
```

Good Query

```
select *, 
  (select stime 
    from racetype_standards 
    where eventID = 7 and stypeID=st.id and gender = 2 and division = 1) 
    as standscore, 
  (select floor(stime / 60) 
    from racetype_standards 
    where eventID = 7 and stypeID=st.id and gender = 2 and division = 1) 
    as standminutes, 
  (select (stime % 60)
    from racetype_standards 
    where eventID = 7 and stypeID=st.id and gender = 2 and division = 1) 
    as standseconds, 
  (select substring_index(stime, '.', -1) 
    from racetype_standards
    where eventID = 7 and stypeID=st.id and gender = 2 and division = 1) 
    as standhunds, 
  (select ecomment 
    from racetype_standards 
    where eventID = 7 and stypeID=st.id and gender = 2 and division = 1) 
    as ecomm 
  from standards_type st 
  where active = 1 
  order by displayOrder
```

Comment: What is the question? PS: please format your queries to be multi-line.

Comment: So with `eventID=7` and the other conditions you get only one match, but with `eventId=8` there's more than one ... and as the error message says: you can only have subqueries returning a single row when using them in the select field list

Comment: I don't understand how the good query relates to the rest of the opening post. Maybe that need to be clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of these:

```
(select stime 
    from racetype_standards 
    where eventID = 8 and stypeID=st.id and gender = 2 and division = 1)
```

must resolve to exactly one row - there cannot be two rows that meet these criteria for any given `st.id`.  If there *are* two rows, then you need to group by `st.id` in each of the inner queries and somehow summarize `stime` (pick `max(stime)` for example) and the same for each of the other subqueries.

Alternately, construct this very differently - probably by doing a join - if you want to be able to return multiple rows for each racetype_standards row.  As it stands this is a *very* hard to maintain query because it's doing the same thing 5 times [basically] - it would be *much* shorter if you modified it to only need that subquery once (for example, by making it into a join).  In my more commonly used flavor of SQL I would perform the subquery once and then refer to the newly created column to do all of the other bits, for example (not sure if that's possible in mysql); additionally, I would only pull the time once and would leave it up to the destination text builder (ie, PHP) to construct the minutes/seconds/whatnot on its own - much less code to maintain.

However, either way I would try to make this a join - seems like you will need all of the various eventIDs eventually right?  Just pull the table down once then deal with it from there.